# Per-project Fabric settings, how?

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

Sorry for the trivial question:
I manage multiple projects, each one is deployed or interacts with one or more server(s).

I maintain my main fabric.py in home. Now, since projects come and go every day, is there a way to define per-project settings with Fabric (or other system), but not in the `fabric.py`? I'm aware of `roledefs` in Fabric, but I really want to separate the Fabric defs from server access data.

e.g.

#### Main fabfile

```
/home/fradeve/fabric.py

def deploy():
    some commands
    pass
```

#### Project's dir

```
/home/fradeve/projects
  |
  |--> project1/.fabricrc
  |--> project2/.fabricrc
  \--> project3/.fabricrc
```

When launching a project, it should read its own `.fabricrc`, read server settings and deploy accordingly.

The problem is that I usually work in the main project dir (`project1`) and starting Fabric with the fabfile outside the project dir (in home) will give me an error.

Any hint on how to manage?

Comment: I've solved loading the `.fabricrc` when issuing `fab` command using the code in [this comment](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/pull/586#issuecomment-5832629). It seems that `fabricrc` is not loaded by default as one could imagine reading the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with writing my own script to handle this.

Starting from the marvelous fabfile from [Alexey Bezhan](https://github.com/allait/allait.github.com/blob/master/static/code/fabfile.py), I've added Vagrant support and a function to create all needed files for a new project (`.vimrc`, `Vagrantfile`, `.gitignore`, etc).

Every project server(s) is defined in a per-project `server_config.yaml`, with easily customizable options. All functions are documented in the script, hope this will be useful for someone. My enhanced version of the script is [here](https://github.com/fradeve/dotfiles/blob/master/home/fabfile.py).